# Can't call props child function

Tags: javascript, function, react-native, react-props

I want to call a function in parent component when a button is pressed in 
child component,

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.Quiz = this.getQuizpopup.bind(this); //Function I want to call 

    this.state = {
      latitude: LATITUDE,
    }

  };
}
```

And in child component, I use to call the function as following

```
<View>
  <Button onPress={this.props.Quiz()} buttonStyle={styles.buttonStyle} title="MpTest" />
</View>
```

The error I am getting is 
[image]

Comment: should be `this.Quiz` - since your Quiz function isn't in the props

Comment: Can you add the full code from `Home` component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a prop as callback in the child component which upon click can trigger the function call in the parent.

Your code should look like below:

```
class Home extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.Quiz = this.getQuizpopup.bind(this); //Function I want to call 
     this.state = {
      latitude: LATITUDE,
     }
  }

  Quiz = () => {
    //button click handler.
  }

  render () {
     return (
        <Child
           onQuizButtonClick = {this.Quiz} />
     ) 
  }
}
```

and in your child the code should be :

```
  <Button onPress={() => this.props.onQuizButtonClick()} buttonStyle={styles.buttonStyle} title="MpTest" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass props to use that function in your child component.

```
class Parent extends Component{
quiz = () => {
  //function you want to call
}
render(){
return(
  <Child quiz={this.quiz}> //passing quiz function as prop to child component 
)
}}
```